# Cannot stop IBM DB2 instance using Data Studio

Tags: db2

I can connect to the SAMPLE database.  However, I cannot stop DB2 10.5 instance using Data Studio 4.1.1.  Here is the screenshot with the error message.

[image]

Comment: Is IBM DAS (data administration service) working?

Comment: This is not a programming question.

Comment: @user4419802 Thank you but I just found that DAS has been deprecated since DB2 9.7.  http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_9.7.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.wn.doc/doc/i0059276.html

Comment: @wannik Yes, but DataStudio uses it (at least on Windows).

Comment: I ran a command `./db2admin start`  It said `The DB@ Administration Server is already active`.  But I still get the error message.

Answer (score 0):

In order for Data Studio to start/stop and instance, it will leverage SSH or DAS, so that we can execute commands. DAS when the database is local on Windows, SSH otherwise. We will need to ask additional questions to understand your OS and your overall configuration. In order to do this, I would suggest to post this within the Data Studio forum at:
https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/forums/html/forum?id=11111111-0000-0000-0000-000000001086

Thanks,
~Loic@IBM

Comment: I can start the instance via Data Studio as db2inst1.  However, when I try to stop the instance, I still got the error message.  I'm using Ubuntu 14.04.